# Get a list of the tags for the objects in an s3 bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to store images for a gallery website in s3 and store description / title information for that image in the s3 object tags. I am wondering if there is a way that I can get a list of the object names with their tags into angular? Or given an object name can I get the tags into angular?

Comment: can you give any code example ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the S3 metadata,  here is the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html).

```
var params = { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "myfile.txt" }; s3.headObject(params, function(err, data) { console.log(data.Metadata['x-amz-(nameofyourmetadata)']); });
```

UPDATE :

Don't forget to fix the CORS configuration of your bucket

```
<CORSRule> <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin> <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod> <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-description</ExposeHeader> </CORSRule>
```

Comment: Im getting some weird cors error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I edited my response,  you need to fix the CORS configuration, allowing your metadata

Comment: So this is getting me the metadata field from properties, but when I just print the object the tags are not contained anywhere

Comment: Can you print what the headobject gives ?

Comment: I figured it out, I ended up using s3.getObjectTagging and it works perfectly. It was kind of hidden in the aws docs, thank you though